# Associative Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to use a variable (which is a value that is imputed in a textbox) in an
 Associative Multidimensional Array and print out the rest of the array values associated with it.

here is what i have so far that doesnt work

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="newcal.php">

<table>
<tr>
    <td> Item #: </td>
    <td> <input type=text name= txtitem > <br> </td>

    <td>
    </td>
    <td> <fieldset style = "width:60px">
        <input type=submit value = "Get Data" name= getdata>
        <input type=submit value = "Add to Cart" name= addto>
        <input type=submit value = "Get Total" name= gettotal>
        </fieldset>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
$item = isset($_POST['txtitem']);


$stuff = array(
             array("id" => 1,"name" => "Apples","price" => 50 ),
             array("id" => 2,"name" => "Pineapples","price" => 125 ),
             array("id" => 3,"name" => "Mango","price" => 35 ),
             array("id" => 4,"name" => "Banana","price" => 25 ),
             array("id" => 5,"name" => "Naseberry","price" => 38 ));


            if(isset($_POST['getdata']))
            {

                foreach ($stuff as $row) 
                {
                    if ($row['id'] == $item) 
                    {
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $price = $row['price'];

                    }
                }
            echo $name;
            echo $price;
            }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you format your PHP code such that it is readable? There are a number of syntax errors which are visible, not sure if this because of how you pasted in content.

Comment: The code snippets here only support JavaScript/HTML/CSS, not PHP.

Comment: So... ***what*** doesn't work?  What's with all the random spaces all over? `name=g etdata`, `i sset($_POST[ 'txtitem'])`  ***Please*** fix/format your code, ***and*** tell us *exactly* what's wrong.  What does this code do/not do?  What do you expect it to do?  P.S. You *need* to quote your HTML attributes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I've rolled back your edit as it fixes syntax errors that could easily be part of the question.

Comment: i assume the spaces are a typo ? `name=t xtitem` but you still need quotes

Comment: @scrowler: Right after I edited it, I realized that.  Good call :-)

Comment: My problem is that when i enter a value in the item item # and press the get data button nothing comes up

Comment: What's `newcal.php`?

Comment: that is the name of the page the it goes to when a button in pushed (which is the same page this code is on)

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is with the following line:

```
$item = isset($_POST['txtitem']);
```

$item is being set to a boolean value.  You probably want something like this:

```
$item = (isset($_POST['txtitem']) ? intval($_POST['txtitem']) : null);
```